# Hidden view is visible in custom UITableViewCell on rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell implemented as a NIB. The custom cell includes a UILabel and UIView (ala new email / message indicator). In `cellForRowAt` I set the lable to some text and hide the UIView but setting its `isHidden` property to false. The result is a list of rows with only a line of text as expected. However if I were to rotate the screen to landscape and then back to portrait, several of the rows that were not visible in landscape but now are in portrait have the UIView visible! If these rows are scrolled off the view and back into it the UIView is hidden as expected. I can recreate this issue in a very simple sample where

UIViewController
  UITableView leading=0, trailing=0, top=0, bottom=0

UITableViewCell
  UIStackView - axis=horizontal, alignment=center, distribution=fill, leading=0, trailing=0, top=0, bottom=0
    UILabel
    UIView - width=10, height=10

Any thoughts on the cause of this behaviour? I have tried setting `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in `cellForRowAt` with no success.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As requested `cellForRowAt` code attached.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.indicatorView.isHidden = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is possible due to cell reusability, Can you please attach your cellForRowAt delegate method code here

Comment: @DharaPatel as requested the code has been included to the post.

Comment: Just to test can you please check adding cell.indicatorView.isHidden = false in your cellForRowAt method and test it's behaviour

Comment: @DharaPatel Do you mean set it to `true`? If `cell.indicatorView.isHidden = true` the behaviour is the same as the post. If `cell.indicatorView.isHidden = false` every row has the view visible as expected.

Comment: cell.indicatorView.isHidden = true for all conditions ?

Comment: @jawadAli This is just a sample project to highlight / test the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its reusability issue .... in your `TableViewCell` override ... `prepareToReuse()`.. and set default value there ...

```
func prepareForReuse()
```

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:). For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view'€™s delegate in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

hide indicator view in storyboard too

[image]

Comment: can you send sample project ? to look into it ?

Comment: send it via wetransfer

Comment: Yes I can. How do I get your email addy?

Comment: you dont need it ... you can send without email

Comment: Here is the link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a893e180b13f7ab8ce657ba107aef7e320200511233435/72fb3b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213655/discussion-between-jawadali-and-chamitha).

Comment: As suggested by @jawadAli hiding the `indicatorView` in the Storyboard does fix this issue. However in a more complex cell with many controls, all will need to be hidden in the Storyboard which is not ideal. I would still like to understand the cause of the issue (is it a bug in the layout engine?) and any other possible workarounds.